# How do you decide whether your function should use a pointer as is receiver?

Tags: go

Consider a binary tree node:

```
type Node struct {
    value uint8
    left, right *Node
}
```

If I want to add a function to each Node, should it be:

```
A:  func (n *Node) height() int
```

or

```
B:  func (n Node) height() int
```

I want to know which of A or B you would choose and why.

I can model linked lists or recursive structs, but I don't know when the receiver should be a pointer or not-a-pointer.

Comment: The Go FAQ deals with this exact question: http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is the idea of `pass by value` vs `pass by reference`

When you're using example A you're passing be reference, meaning that any changes you apply to `n` inside of `func (n *Node) height` will apply to the Node you're using to call `Node.height()`.

By comparison, what you're doing in example B is passing by value where you're really just passing a copy of the Node you're using to call `Node.height()` so any changes to that Node will not apply outside of the function.

Here is a small playground to demonstrate the differences: http://play.golang.org/p/JodPRPBHDg

Notice in the example that when you call `node.incHeight()`, it goes to the function:

```
func (n Node) incHeight() uint8 {
  n.value++
  return n.value
}
```

Because this is pass by value the `node.value` is still the same unless you store the returned value as `node.value`. However, if you call `node.incrementHeight()` it goes to the function:

```
func (n *Node) incrementHeight() {
  n.value++
  return
}
```

This will change the value of `node.value` without needing to return anything because its referencing the original struct, rather than a copy of the struct.

So in answer to which would you choose and why, it really depends on whether you want to be able to make lasting changes to the struct you're using to call the function or if you'd rather just pass a copy that can see and alter the values but only while within the function and not have any lasting effects on the original struct.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very nice explanation in https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/Style

> **Receiver Type**
>
> Choosing whether to use a value or pointer receiver on
> methods can be difficult, especially to new Go programmers. If in
> doubt, use a pointer, but there are times when a value receiver makes
> sense, usually for reasons of efficiency, such as for small unchanging
> structs or values of basic type. Some rules of thumb:
>
> - If the receiver is a map, func or chan, don't use a pointer to it.
> - If the receiver is a slice and the method doesn't reslice or    reallocate the slice, don't use a pointer to it.
> - If the method needs to mutate the receiver, the receiver must be a    pointer.
> - If the receiver is a struct that contains a sync.Mutex or similar    synchronizing field, the receiver must be a pointer to avoid copying.
> - If the receiver is a large struct or array, a pointer receiver is    more efficient. How large is large? Assume it's equivalent to passing
>   all its elements as arguments to the method. If that feels too large,
>   it's also too large for the receiver.
> - Can function or methods, either concurrently or when called from this    method, be mutating the receiver? A value type creates a copy
>   of the    receiver when the method is invoked, so outside updates will
>   not be    applied to this receiver. If changes must be visible in the
>   original    receiver, the receiver must be a pointer.
> - If the receiver is a struct, array or slice and any of its elements    is a pointer to something that might be mutating, prefer a pointer
>   receiver, as it will make the intention more clear to the reader.
> - If the receiver is a small array or struct that is naturally a value    type (for instance, something like the time.Time type), with
>   no    mutable fields and no pointers, or is just a simple basic type
>   such    as int or string, a value receiver makes sense. A value
>   receiver can    reduce the amount of garbage that can be generated; if
>   a value is    passed to a value method, an on-stack copy can be used
>   instead of    allocating on the heap. (The compiler tries to be smart
>   about    avoiding this allocation, but it can't always succeed.) Don't
>   choose    a value receiver type for this reason without profiling
>   first.
> - Finally, when in doubt, use a pointer receiver.